# Use method in ResourceBundle Javascript object for internationalization

Tags: jquery, internationalization, javascript-objects

I have following resourceBundle Javascript object.

```
var resourceBundle = {
  en : {
        "MSG1" : "Message 1",
        "MSG2" : "Message 2"
  }
}
```

As you see, this is for english. Then I can create another brance for, say, French(fr). No problem to get 'Message 1' , 'Message 2' as all I have to do is get resourceBundle['en'][key]. But what I can do if I want a message to be created using paramaters. Can I use methods, if so, how.

What I mean is something like this, I want to add MSG3 as;

```
"MSG3" : "welcome "+userName;
```

not exact way, a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
resourceBundle['fr'] = []; // create new
resourceBundle['fr']['MSG1'] = "test"; // add value

alert(resourceBundle['fr']['MSG1']); // test
```

or using @David's answer as a base :

```
function createMessage(key, value, locale) {
    if (resourceBundle[locale] == undefined) {
        resourceBundle[locale] = [];
    }
    resourceBundle[locale][key] = value;
}

createMessage('Pardon my french', 'MSG1', 'FR');
```

Comment: please refer the edited question.pardon me I was nit clear before

Comment: @ghTvNath same answer - you just pass your parameter ie `createMessage('message ' + username,'MSG1','FR');`